# "Couldn't be more wrong" or "is wrong", facing trouble in correlating the expressions

Tags: phrases, expressions

When someone says "I couldn't be more wrong", how is the phrase synonymous to saying that is way off mark. I am not getting a feel of this negation statement. Can anyone please explain me elaborately with an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Latin, there is a phrase that goes,

> *Mea culpa. Mea maxima culpa.*

Translation: I'm to blame. I'm fully to blame.

In other words, the person saying this is admitting to having done something wrong. To his credit, he is not attempting to make excuses for his behavior or to blame someone else for what he alone has done wrong.

The sentence you are having difficulty with is similar in meaning to the Latin "Mea culpa."

The person who says "I couldn't be more wrong," is not just saying "I'm wrong," but he is admitting his degree of wrongness is great; in fact, it could not be greater.

Normally, admitting you are wrong to someone you have wronged is sufficient to receive their forgiveness. ***Quantifying*** your ***degree*** of wrongness by saying "I couldn't be ***more*** wrong" is unusual, but you communicate both humility and regret for having committed the wrong.

Comment: when you say the phrase "it could not be greater" does it means less great. When something is not greater then one has two options left i.e. being greatest or demote to great. How should I interpret that ?

Comment: @noob_python: No. "It could not be greater" means: Whatever IT IS, it has achieved greatness that cannot be surpassed. In other words, it can't get any greater. When I say, "My joy in seeing you again after six, long years, could not be greater," I mean my joy in seeing you again could not be any greater. Put differently, "I am experiencing maximum joy in seeing you after six years."

Comment: It is more clear now @rhetorician. Thank you